# ActionListener Unorthodox Infinate Frame Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener

So I'm trying to get my ActionListener to work when I click on the button. Whenever I create a frame though, (the error seems to be happening in the createComponents() method, and I can not see why) the JVM keeps generating infinite instances of the MyCustomFrame object.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MyCustomFrame extends JFrame
{
private JButton button;
private JLabel label;
private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 800;
private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 800;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    MyCustomFrame frame = new MyCustomFrame();
    frame.setTitle("My first frame");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public MyCustomFrame()
{
    setTitle("My Custom Frame");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(FRAME_WIDTH,FRAME_HEIGHT);
    setVisible(true);
    createComponents();
}

private void createComponents()
{
    button = new JButton("Click me!");
    ClickListener listener = new ClickListener();
    button.addActionListener(listener);
    label = new JLabel("Hello, World!");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(button);
    panel.add(label);
    add(panel);
}

class ClickListener extends MyCustomFrame implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        label.setText("Button was clicked.");
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class ClickListener extends MyCustomFrame implements ActionListener
```

A MouseListener has no reason to extend a Frame. Show every time you create the listener you create another frame, which creates another listener and so on.

The code should just be:

```
class ClickListener implements ActionListener
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should do it like this

```
button.addActionListener(this)
```

Then create a method in the same class  that is like this

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    label.setText("Button was clicked.");
}
```

At least this works for me